# Include content with php

Tags: php, switch-statement

I want to create a Wordpress like function using php to load variable content in a single page. To better understand what I want to achieve, here is an example: I have an index.php file. It includes three parts (header, content and footer) via php "include" command. Now the header and footer is same for all pages, but I need to be able to include different content in the same page (based on which navigation anchor I click). The problem is that unless I have specific base url (I don't have one because base url would be same index.php) I don't know how to pull specific content. Kindly let me know if this is possible? If yes, how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a GET parameter to decide what content to load. `index.php?content=foo`. (How to access that value inside your script is something any halfway decent beginner’s tutorial should be able to explain to you.)

Comment: [so] is not for design discussions. You need to ask specific questions about actual code you've written, not general questions about how to create your application.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments made, however, I also believe it would be a shame if you didn't try and learn something new yourself today! Tip: there are many ways to do what you want to do, more or less sophisticated, so don't hold back and dive into some tutorials; I hope this will motivate you (and keep you from running to WP)!

So, to help you to get started, set up the following directory structure:

[image]

1. We have a content folder with all the different pages you would want to 'navigate to'
2. We have a `header.php` and `footer.php` that are pulled in on every request to `index.php`.
3. We have `index.php`, the page where all the magic happens.

Let's have a look at the code(I'm assuming you're running this on `localhost`):

`header.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
</head>
<body>
<a href = "http://localhost/your/path/to/index.php?page=page0">page0</a>
<a href = "http://localhost/your/path/to/index.php?page=page1">page1</a>
```

In `header.php` we define two `<a href =...>` 's. These link to the same destination, `index.php`, but they each set a different query string variable: `?page=page0` and `?page=page1`.

Query string variable `page` will be picked up by `index.php` through `$_GET['page']` to pull-in the content for either `page0.php` or `page1.php` respectively.

`index.php`

```
<?php

require "header.php";

if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $target = "content/" . $_GET['page'] . ".php";
    require $target;
}

require "footer.php";
```

As you can see, `index.php` waits for `$_GET['page']` to be set, i.e. a link to be clicked, to then pick up the information set in `$_GET['page']` variable and use it to `require` the correct content (i.e. `page0.php` or `page1.php`).

Closing off your HTML with a proper footer...

`footer.php`

```
</body>
</html>
```

And finally, the content pages:

`page0.php`

```
<?php
echo "Page 0 content";
```

`page1.php`

```
<?php
echo "Page 1 content";
```

Comment: Well, that explains it all. Thanks. I am new to this and to avoid WordPress. This helps a lot.